# Python fast data structure for truncatable circular buffer

Tags: python, performance

I am maintaining logs in a list currently of the last 1000000 entries by just using log.append(line). To make sure it doesn't get too long when the size gets to 2000000 I copy do log = log[1000000:] .  However this is rather slow.

In C I could use a linked list to just move the pointer to the position of the middle of the log.  However this isn't a great solution as I can no longer jump to particular entries in the log quickly.

Is there a python solution that allows me to truncate the log wherever I want, add things to the end of the log but still allow fast access to log[i] ?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That has the same problem doesn't it?  I want to be able to truncate quickly.

Comment: When the length becomes `1000001` do you want the list to contain `1000001` items or `1000000`?

Comment: What would be the problem with moving the equivalent of a "pointer" (e.g. an integer index) to the middle of the list in Python?  I suspect that a proper circular buffer implementation would negate these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

> Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from
>   either side of the deque with approximately the same **O(1)** performance
>   in either direction

For python versions before py2.6:

When appending check for the length, if the length is greater than 1000000 then do a `popleft` to remove the left-most item, so that the list will always contain the last `1000000` items.

If your python version in py2.6+ then simply take the advantage of `maxlen` argument:

> If **maxlen** is not specified or is None, deques may grow to an arbitrary
>   length. Otherwise, the deque is bounded to the specified maximum
>   length. Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added,
>   a corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end.
>   Bounded length deques provide functionality similar to the tail filter
>   in Unix. They are also useful for tracking transactions and other
>   pools of data where only the most recent activity is of interest.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `deque`, from the standard library:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

It supports a fixed maximum length, which might do automatically what you are looking for, from the documentation:

> If `maxlen` is not specified or is None, deques may grow to an arbitrary
>   length. Otherwise, the deque is bounded to the specified maximum
>   length. Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added,
>   a corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NumPy http://www.numpy.org: it includes, among other things, "a powerful N-dimensional array object...Besides its obvious scientific uses, NumPy can also be used as an efficient multi-dimensional container of generic data."

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with list.pop(0) ? Ie when you reach a certain length, instead of l`og.append(l)` you do

```
log.append(line)
log.pop(0)
```

Of course this does not truncate to a particular size, but rather keeps the list to a limited size.

Comment: list.pop is an `O(N)` operation.